# Adding textview dynamically in linear layout

Tags: android, android-layout

Sorry if this is duplicate post but I am not able to find my answer in similar posts.

So, my requirement is:

I have a linearlayout which have some textViews and editviews. Now I want to add one textview below existing editview at runtime.

The layout is a linear Layout and orientation is vertical.

I am very new to android programming. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Please add some of the relevant code if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you have as many as you need in your xml with `visibility:gone` and switch them to `mTextView.setVisibility(TextView.VISIBLE)`or as the one above me who just answered

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is exactly what I wanted. Other's are also correct but not fulfilling my requirement.
Sorry, I can't mark answers as useful because lack of reputation.

Answer (score 0):

**Use this:**

```
TextView tv1 = new TextView(this);
tv1.setText("FIRST");
tv1.setTextSize(10);
tv1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);



LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
ll.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
ll.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
ll.addView(tv1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
TextView textView = new TextView(mContext);
        textView.setText("Your text");
        mLinearLayout.addView(mTextView);
```

You can add any View in a LinearLayout using the method: **addView**